# Watchdog prints path on windows which os.startfile cannot open but if you use same path manually it works

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I have simple python program monitoring a directory using watchdog with `FilesystemEventHandler` defined as below

```py
import time
import os 
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class Watcher:
    INCOMING_DIR = "C:/Users/username/documents/test/Incoming/"
    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.INCOMING_DIR, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()


        self.observer.join()

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        PROCESSED_DIR = "C:/Users/username/documents/test/Processed/"
        INCOMING_DIR = "C:/Users/username/documents/test/Incoming/"
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            print ("Received created event - %s." % event.src_path)
            filename = Path(event.src_path).name
            print (filename)
            print (repr(event.src_path))
            os.startfile(event.src_path , "print")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

Which outputs value of `event.src_path` in print properly like

```
Received created event - C:/Users/username/documents/test/Incoming/sample.txt.
sample.txt
'C:/Users/username/documents/test/Incoming/sample.txt'
```

But when the `os.startfile` tries to open it I get error

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:/Users/username/documents/test/Incoming/sample.txt'
```

The reason why I use `os.startfile` is that eventually this is supposed to print out the files automatically using

```
os.startfile(path, "print")
```

If I test it with simple python script

```py
import os

os.startfile('C:/Users/username/documents/test/Incoming/sample.txt', "open")
```

It opens just fine. File definitely exists in the path

Watchdog documentation does not really give insight on if it does something weird to filenames on windows so this is extremely confusing.

The goal is to  to have watchdog event of file created to initially open a file and in long run print it using `os.startfile` but it complains on windows that system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [code formatting help](/editing-help#code). I fixed this one's formatting for you :) Also check out [ask] for more tips.

Comment: i added an import, but the question still needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added reproducible sample and cleaned formatting

Comment: If you use `"print"` in your "simple python script", does that work?  Perhaps you do not have a "print" handler defined for ".txt" files.

Comment: It is not just "print" that fails, even when it is "open" the same result. Works fine when using os.startfile('C:/Users/username/documents/test/Incoming/sample.txt', "print"). I have tested couple of different commands (ie os.rename)  and when using that event.src_path as parameter they all seem to complain about not being able to find the file, thus the original suspicion that there might be something weird in the output of that.